# Mutation fires twice with react-adopt

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, react-adopt

I am using `react-adopt` with `react-apollo`. The simple reason for this is that having a large number of queries and mutations on a single page gets very messy.

## Issue

- When firing `mut1` only one mutation will happen.
- When firing `mut2`,`mut2` fires and then `mut1` fires once `mut2` finishes.
- If I had a `mu3,4,5 etc` and I clicked `mut3` it would run `mut3` > `mut2`and
- the finally `mut1` If you ran `mut5` it would then do `4 > 3 > 2 > 1` etc...

## Component

```
const mut1 = () => {
  return (
    <Mutation mutation={MUTATION} {...props} />
  )
}
const mut2 = () => {
  return <Mutation mutation={MUTATION2} {...props} />
}
export default
  adopt({
    mut1,
    mut2,
  }
)
```

I would of course like each mutation to only fire once when clicked.

Answer (score 0):

create `MutationContainer.js` which contain all your mutation export MutationContainer as a variable

```
import { gql } from 'apollo-boost'
import { adopt } from 'react-adopt'

const mutation1 = () => (
  <Mutation mutation={MUTATION1} {...props} />
)
const mutation2 = () => (
  <Mutation mutation={MUTATION2} {...props} />
)
const mutation3 = () => (
  <Mutation mutation={MUTATION3} {...props} />
)
export const MutationContainer = adopt({
  mutation1,
  mutation2,
  mutation3
})
```

Import it on any component where you want to use this mutations

on your Component1.jsx

```
import { adopt } from 'react-adopt'
import { Value } from 'react-powerplug'

import { MutationContainer } from './MutationContainer'

const Composed = adopt({
  input: <Value initial="" />,
  container: <MutationContainer />,
})

export const Component1 = () => (
  <Composed>
    {({ container: { mutation1 }, input }) => {
      const handleAdd = ev => {
        mutation1.mutation({ variables: { ...variables } })
        input.setValue('')
        ev.preventDefault()
      }
      return (
        <Form onSubmit={handleAdd}>
          <Input
            type="text"
            value={input.value}
            onChange={ev => input.setValue(ev.target.value)}
          />
          <Button type="submit">Let's call mutation1</Button>
        </Form>
      )
    }}
  </Composed>
)
```

On Component2.jsx

```
import { adopt } from 'react-adopt'
import { Value } from 'react-powerplug'
import { MutationContainer } from './MutationContainer'

const Composed = adopt({
  input: <Value initial="" />,
  container: <MutationContainer />,
})

export const Component2 = () => (
  <Composed>
    {({ container: { mutation2, mutation3 }, loading }) => {

      const handleMutation2 = async () => {
        await mutation2.mutation({ variables: { ...variables } })
      }
      const handleMutation3 = async () => {
        await mutation3.mutation({ variables: { ...variables } })
      }
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <Button onClick={handleMutation2}>
           Let's call mutation2
          </Button>
          <Button onClick={handleMutation3}>
            Let's call mutation3
          </Button>
        <React.Fragment>
      )
    }}
  </Composed>
)
```

Please take care of variables as par your requirement

And most important point based on your condition

```
export const App = () => (
  <MutationContainer>
    {({ data: { loading, data } }) => (
        <React.Fragment>
         <Component1  {...this.props }/>
         <Component2 {...this.props } />
        </React.Fragment>
    )}
  </MutationContainer>
)
```

If you persist this problem please let me know. will try `react-adopt` with new approach.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to fill this in for me.

I will say, it seems like the same issue would occur, only that you are moving the mutations into their own container. I don't see why this would make a difference, but I will give it a go and see where this can take me. Could you please explain why you think this would make a difference?

Comment: I thought when you click on mutation1 it will also call mutation2, mutation3 and so on internally without any condition.  when we create own container we seprate mutation to call or one mutation at a time. It worked for me. But i don't have problem like you. Feel sorry. Thanks

Comment: No, When you click one, it fires one without a problem. Please re-read the question :) When you click 1, 1 fires, when you click 2, 2 fires, finishes then 1 fires.

Comment: They are interchanged on click on mutation2 it calls mutation1 when finish.

Comment: Why do they interchange? With my example or in general?

Comment: They are not interchanging they are calling use console on every mutation why they calling and where from they called. May help thanks

Comment: I would like it so only `mutation 2` executes when you click `mutation 2`. I do not want `mutation `1 to fire with clicking `mutation2`